# How to use The Schwarzchild Metric formula to get distribution representing "free-fall"

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, probability, free-fall, geodesics

Given formula:

[image]

How I can use to calculate distribution of points in space, so if i choose path which contains most of the points I get path that close to "free-fall path".
As far as I know i should use square root of Determinant of given formula to do this, but i am not sure.

Please, be gentle, I am computer scientist student that in process writing black hole simulation for academic purposes.
NOTE: Simulation is in 2D. so some parameters may be irrelevant.

Comment: Are you trying to compute the orbit of a mass around a black hole?

Comment: I want to calculate distribution formula that will help me to draw points in space, so that in we choose "free fall" path. That path will have maximum amount of points than any other path.

Comment: I am not sure I recognize the method for the path calculations from 'distributions of points' you are referring to. Can you give examples, may be for newtonian mechanics?

Comment: But any geodesic is a *free-fall path*, isn't it? Have you tried this article on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_geodesics)

Comment: A possible path is continues. I would like to treat it as if it is discrete, and I would like more "nodes" to appear in the free-fall path, as derived from the formula above. I hope this is clearer.

Comment: @Simone you will eventually arrive at a differential equation that you may directly integrate (in this particular spherically symmetric problem) or solve as an ODE, as you please. If you solve the ODE as such, you may use a Runge-Kutta method with a step controlled by you. The curve describing the motion (may it be an obit or not) will be no more than a collection of discrete points, whose sparseness you control.

Comment: @Simone contd. This [article](http://astronomia.udea.edu.co/sitios/astronomia-2.0/pages/descargas.rs/files/descargasdt5vi/Cursos/CursosRegulares/Relatividad/2010-1/Papers/AJP000045.pdf) may be particularly useful to you, but this is also done in most textbooks of introduction to GR.